# Finding the wave function at all times for a particle trapped in an infinite potential well, given the initial wave function of the particle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, schroedinger-equation

A particle is trapped in the region $0 \leq x \leq \pi$ by an infinite potential well. At the initial time, the particle has a
wavefunction
$\psi(x, 0)=A(\sin (x)+\sin (2 x))$.
Find the wavefunction at all times:
$\psi(x, t)=$

The question first asked to find $A$, assuming the wavefunction is normalized.
I found $A$ to be the $\sqrt{\frac{1}{\pi}}$.

The second part says to find the wavefunction at all times.
I went about this by solving for the $c_n$ coefficients (following the Fourier series method) however, I found all $c_n$ to be equal to zero. So the wave equation is zero at all times.

Is this correct? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: $c_n$ are not equal to zero. Could you show us how you calculated $c_n$? Also make if you type $ around your equations they become Mathjax (Latex) which makes it easier to read. For more help on Mathjax visit https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.